# Calculate: $ 121:11(10+1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My simple question is here:

Calculate:

> $$ 121:11(10+1)$$

Why should it be $121:11(10+1)≠1$, I don't know.

$121:11(10+1)=121:121=1$

Another way: $\frac{121}{11(10+1)}=\frac{121}{121}=1$

Why is this wrong?

Comment: The way you state it, the answer is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Another way: $\frac{121}{11}(10+1)=121$. This problem is ambiguous, and claiming that one interpretation is correct and another is false is plain wrong.

Multiplication and division, for some reason, doesn't have a similar "left-to-right" convention that addition and subtraction has (nor any other convention for that matter). For instance, it is generally agreed that
$$
10-5+2=7
$$
while
$$
10:5\cdot2
$$ is unclear and should be avoided at all costs. You should always use parentheses and fraction lines to make the order of division and multiplication clear.

Comment: Why is unclear? All computers, calculation machines and  scientific software given the same answer?

Comment: @MathLover Because there are enough people out there that learn in school that one has precedence over the other. Just look at any time such a question is discussed on facebook.

Comment: @MathLover Also, I know for a fact that there are calculators that would answer $121$ on this and there are calculators that would answer $1$, especially because of the implied multiplication between 11 and the bracket, which gets higher precedence than division and ordinary multiplication some times. And you would want that in cases like dividing by $2\pi$, so it's not an unreasonable functionality.

Answer (score 0):

What is the difference between

> $121:11(10+1)$ and $121:(11(10+1)) ?$

Have you tried?
I think this is enough.

Update:

> $121:11(10+1)=121:11×11=11×11=121$
>
> $121:(11(10+1))=121:(11×11)=121:121=1$